# Screen reader not reading tooltip bubble message

Tags: handlebars.js, accessibility

I am trying to get my ChromeVox screen reader to read the bubble message that pops up when the user tabs over to the tooltip icon, but it doesn't and the documentation out there is not very clear on what I thought should have been a simple solution.

this is the code in the file I am trying to refactor to get the screen reader to read the tooltip:

```
<div class="sub-item content-spaced">
      <span class="text" tabindex="0">{{translations.taxEstLabel}}</span>
      {{#hasEstimatedTax}}
        <span class="value" tabindex="0">{{totalEstimatedTax}}</span>
      {{/hasEstimatedTax}}
      {{^hasEstimatedTax}}
        <div class="tooltip" role="tooltip" tabindex="0" data-info-text="{{translations.taxEstMessage}}"></div>
      {{/hasEstimatedTax}}
    </div>
```

This is a Handlebarjs template by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Handlebarjs but your `<div>` that's a tooltip doesn't appear to have any text between the `<div>` and `</div>`.  Is the text injected in between when the div receives focus?  If text is inserted, I'm guessing when the div receives focus, the screen reader will announce what's in currently in the div (which is nothing), and then your js code runs that injects the text.

If this is how it works, then you can add [`aria-live="polite"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) to the div.  That will allow the screen reader to read any text changes in the div.

```html
<div aria-live="polite" class="tooltip" role="tooltip" tabindex="0" data-info-text="{{translations.taxEstMessage}}"></div>
```

As a side question, why do your `<span>` and `<div>` elements have `tabindex="0"`?  I know tabindex will allow the keyboard focus to move to the element, but generally you shouldn't set tabindex on a non-interactive element.  If you added tabindex for the sole purpose of allowing a screen reader to tab to the text so that they can hear it being read, that's not necessary.  Screen reader users can navigate to every element in the DOM using various screen reader shortcut keys, such as 'H' to go to the next heading, 'T' to go to the next table, 'L' to go to the next list, etc.  If your html is using semantic elements such as `<h2>`, `<table>`, and `<ul>`, then your code will work great with a screen reader.

Comment: `aria-live="polite"` did not do the trick and in ChromeVox shortcut keys do not work.

Comment: The idea was for the text thats inside `data-info-text` attribute to be read.

Comment: chromevox has shortcut keys too.  they work great for me.  did you set your main chromevox key.  go into settings.  screen readers don't know anything about `data-` attributes.  if you want text to be read that is inserted, then `aria-live` must be used.  it works with jaws, nvda, and voiceover screen readers.